# A problem on configuration of Dao's theorem on six circumcenters

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

**Abstract:** In the figure belows: *Three lines through center of pair opposite red circle are concurrent*. This is a statement of [Dao's theorem on six circumcenter](https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%90%E1%BB%8Bnh_l%C3%BD_%C4%90%C3%A0o_v%E1%BB%81_s%C3%A1u_t%C3%A2m_%C4%91%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Dng_tr%C3%B2n), a new theorem in plane geometry which was discovered by OP in 2013. Also on this configuration, today 05/25/2021, I found that: *Let the green circles are inverse of red circles in black circle $(\Omega)$. Then three lines through center of pair opposite green circle are concurrent*.

I am looking for a proof that:

> **Problem:** *Let $L_1$, $L_2$, $L_3$, $L_4$, $L_5$, $L_6$ be six lines and let $P_{ij}= L_i \cap Lj$, such that $P_{12}$,$P_{23}$, $P_{34}$, $P_{45}$, $P_{56}$, $P_{61}$ lie on a circle $(\Omega)$. Let $(O_{ijk})$ is inverse of circle $(P_{ij}P_{jk}P_{ik})$ in $(\Omega)$. We taking subscripts modulo 6. Then three lines $O_{126}O_{453}$, $O_{231}O_{564}$ and $O_{342}O_{651}$ are concurrent.*

[image]

Comment: How do you produce the figures?

Comment: You can access in website https://www.geogebra.org/ using online or download Geogebra software to draw.

Comment: Dear @ĐàoThanhOai, I have some discoveries on this theorem. How can I contact you?

Comment: @RopuToran Thanks you very much, my gmail is oaidt.evnpsc@gmail.com